# USB Device was working fine, now not, detected, but nothing

Tags: debian, bluetooth, lsusb

I've got an edimax wi-fi ac600 that I've been using for the Bluetooth LE side for a while, but it seems that after an OS update (perhaps), it is no longer functioning.

I can see the device if I do *lsusb*

[image]

However, doing *ls -l /dev/serial/by-id* just gives me the other couple of dongles that are connected.

Trying to do *bluetoothctl* just hangs, which is expected given the bluetooth controller can't be found.

I know the device is fine as it works when connected to a Windows machine and I can see it on the machine here.

Any ideas as to what I can do to get this working again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tired reinstalling drivers? check https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Comment: More ideas here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234651/how-to-install-edimax-ac-600-wi-fi-adapter-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: @esantix wasn't even sure I installed drivers last time, pretty sure I plugged it in and it worked. Did the RTL8812AU install and it said its installed, but not seeing any change.